# Where do I find BILLING_RESULT_OK for Google Play Billing isFeatureSupported call?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

The google play developer documentation for in-app-purchase subscriptions states

> Before your app enters the billing flow, you can call isFeatureSupported() to determine whether the device supports the products you want to sell

When calling this method, it's javadoc states

> returns BILLING_RESULT_OK if feature is supported and corresponding error code otherwise

I cannot locate the `BILLING_RESULT_OK` constant in any of the billing classes and cant find the reference in the documentation. **What is the right value/constant to compare the response code to?**

Is `BILLING_RESULT_OK` the same as `BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.BillingResponseCode#OK)

The documentation hasn't been updated for some time now. Even the [official sample](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/blob/3f640086f2cf524bd7c8255e3b04a49a75a7bf45/TrivialDriveKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/kotlin/trivialdrive/billingrepo/BillingRepository.kt#L732) uses `BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK`.